# Is there a way to click upon the tooltip button element after respectivlilly hovering the tooltip?

Tags: html, css, button, hover, tooltip

Is there a way to click upon the tooltip button element after respectivlilly hovering the tooltip with a native css or do I need a js code only? So make the tooltip not dissapear when cancel hovering the wrapper element.

```js
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tooltip">  //appers on hovering the wrapper element
    <button>Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```